# Removing a <li> from <ol> using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an ordered list

```
<ol id="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>
```

Values can be appended by user to the above list by a click. User wants to remove a value from list. Value decided to be removed is entered in an input field. I could come up with

```
 $("#btn2").click(function(){
   var delitem = $(".Remove").val();
   $("#list").remove($("<li>").text(delitem));
 });
```

But this doesn't work. What is the best way to remove a list item in an ordered list using jquery?

Comment: what is your matching criteria? Only absolute match or partial match?

Comment: Its absolute match for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Will match anything containing delete text using [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  var delitem = $(".Remove").val();
  $("#list > li:contains(" + delitem + ")").remove();
});
```

---

### **Will only match for exact delete text using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  var delitem = $(".Remove").val();
  $("#list li").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === delitem;
  }).remove();
});
```

Comment: Note that contains is not absolute match

Comment: @charlietfl true, in which case they would want to use filter.  But from their example code...i don't think they are getting that complex, it is much more simple.

Comment: But should be noted as it can have unexpected results. Consider one John as first name and another as last name

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out `li` by its text content and then remove it.

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  var delitem = $(".Remove").val();
  $("#list li").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == delitem;
  }).remove();
});
```

---

**FYI :** If there is no need for an exact match then you can use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-class selector which would be much faster than the filter.

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  var delitem = $(".Remove").val();
  $('#list li:contains('+ delitem +')').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var delitem = $(".Remove").val();
    $("#list li").filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() === delItem;
    }).remove();
 });
```

Your code is actually creating a new element that doesn't exist in the dom to even be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`

```
 $("#list li").filter(function(){
    return this.textContent.trim()  === delitem;
 }).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.each()` method which includes its own index variable `i` to keep track of how many iterations the loop has gone through.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#list li').each(function(i){
            if ($('input').val() === $(this).text()) {
                $('#list li').eq(i).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter item to remove..." />
<button type="button">Remove Item</button>
```